# Code Analysis: CA1002: Do not expose generic lists. How to understand this violation

Tags: c#, generics

I've read many post on Do Not Expose Generic but still I don't get the exact resolution for it.
I have written a sample console application that uses List and List as return type and parameters respectively. Upon running code analysis, it says **Do Not Expose Generic List**. [As msdn says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1002-do-not-expose-generic-lists):

> `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` is a generic collection that is designed for performance and not inheritance. `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` does not contain virtual members that make it easier to change the behavior of an inherited class. The following generic collections are designed for inheritance and should be exposed instead of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

And fix is

> To fix a violation of this rule, change the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` type to one of the generic collections that is designed for inheritance.

If I use `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`. I am still able to add items even after function caller. Then what is use of Generic collections.
Below is code:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public static List<Person> AddPersonsToCurrentList(List<Person> personsList )
        {
            personsList.Add(new Person(){ Age = 11, Name = "Vijay" });
            return personsList;
        }
    }
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] ar)
        {
            var personList = new List<Person>()
                                          {
                                              new Person(){Age =10,Name="Vj"} 
                                          };

            var resultList = Person.AddPersonsToCurrentList(personList);
            Console.WriteLine(personList.GetType());
            personList.Add(new Person(){Age = 11, Name = "Ajay"});
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Now if I change return type to `Collection<Person>` and parameter to `Collection<Person>`
The output is the same. As we are exposing a generic list, I changed the return type and parameter list to `ICollection<Person>`/`IEnumerable`. 
If I put `ICollection`. I am still able to add items to it after the method also.
Modified Code:

```
public static ICollection<Person> AddPersonsToCurrentList(Collection<Person> personsList )
        {
            personsList.Add(new Person(){ Age = 11, Name = "Vijay" });
            return personsList;
        }
```

But still I am exposing the Generic Collection, where user can still add items before or after calling the method.
Could anyone please help me how `List<T>` is useful when compared with `Collection<T>` in terms of performance and other various other attributes.

It would great help for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Important question: are you making this API available to other people for whom changing it later would be a big problem? i.e. a public API on a library consumed by customers or third parties? if not - and so changing the API isn't a problem: frankly, ignore it - if you need to change the type later (and that's a big "if"), just **change the type later**. Many code warnings are very contextual, and for most scenarios, this one just doesn't apply.

Comment: Yes. I am dealing with a code base that might handled by external developers. So this is just a prototype. So if I am using List<T> and List<T> as return type(at method signature) and parameter respectively, the other developers who will be calling this method might add items to list which is still a security concern. Even if I change it to collections<T>. It is still an expose of generic collection

Comment: Simple way to avoid this issue: **always use the least derived interface, `IEnumerable<T>`, for public methods**.

Comment: It is a fair warning, there isn't anything you can do about the client programmer using the list wrong.  The Add() method is particularly dangerous, it can trivially crash your own code by adding a wonky object, like null.  So the client programmer did something wrong but the crash occurs in code he did not write and cannot see.  That's a guaranteed support call that is hard to handle.  Matters a lot to Microsoft in particular, this analysis tool was first developed for Microsoft's internal use.  Collection is okay, you can override InsertItem and generate a good diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You are being warned that the List object is inflexible and you are constraining the external developers to use that concrete type. Usually the best practice when developing code that will be available for other developers use, is to require as abstract an implementation as possible, implementing only the functionality that is *needed* in your method.

This allows the end user to supply their own implementation if desired. 
For example, instead of requiring the type `List<Person>`, you could instead depend on `IEnumerable<Person>`, if all you are doing in your method is enumerating through the list.

This grants the flexibility for your API users to implement their own List types/helpers and will still function correctly, as long as they inherit from IEnumerable (Which is a contract that guarantees you can enumerate through your type).

In your example you are asking for a List of type T, *or something that inherits from List of type T*, and are being warned that the concrete type of `List<T>` should not be used for inheritance.